# Dolphin crashes when opening USB drive, "dolphin does not provide a bug reporting address"

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, dolphin

I can't open the dolphin file manager from the tray popup when inserting a new USB drive.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Insert USB thumb drive
2. Click "open with file manager" in the system tray popup.

Effect:
Dolphin crashes, but the error reporting dialog says "You cannot report this error, because dolphin does not provide a bug reporting address". Details: Executable: dolphin, Signal: Segmentation fault (11).

I have both dolphin and dolphin-dbg installed.

What to do?

I trid filing a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378390 but they say it's a Kubuntu bug, and not KDE.

lsb_release gives the folling output:

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got also Dolphin crashing but not in the same context.

May be this workaround will work for you too:
Go to Control Menu > Configure Dolphin > Services > Uncheck "the link to activities"

*Sorry, my version is in french and I don't know the exact label in english ("Module externe de liaison entre fichiers et activités)*

Comment: Yes, that seems to have made the trick!